# while reseting my firebase database for the profiler by using firebase init, my whole html webpack plug in broke

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, webpack, google-cloud-firestore

I got this error and i am new to do this. It is a react app and connected to firestore for uploading and sending data. It was working before i put in the command line "firebase init". I may have rewrote some rules for firestore and hosting but I am confused on what happened.

```
Html Webpack Plugin:
  ReferenceError: features is not defined

  - index.html:701 
    /Users/19mapara_m/Documents/internship/moodi-voting-system/public/index.html    :701:10

  - index.html:704 ./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./public/ind    ex.html.module.exports
    /Users/19mapara_m/Documents/internship/moodi-voting-system/public/index.html    :704:3

  - index.js:264 
    [moodi-voting-system]/[html-webpack-plugin]/index.js:264:16

  - From previous event:

  - index.js:252 HtmlWebpackPlugin.executeTemplate
    [moodi-voting-system]/[html-webpack-plugin]/index.js:252:6

  - index.js:137 
    [moodi-voting-system]/[html-webpack-plugin]/index.js:137:18

  - From previous event:

  - index.js:132 Compiler.
    [moodi-voting-system]/[html-webpack-plugin]/index.js:132:8

  - Tapable.js:206 Compiler.applyPluginsAsyncSeries
    [moodi-voting-system]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:206:13

  - Compiler.js:358 Compiler.emitAssets
    [moodi-voting-system]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:358:8

  - Compiler.js:57 onCompiled
    [moodi-voting-system]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:57:19

  - Compiler.js:514 applyPluginsAsync.err
    [moodi-voting-system]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:514:14

  - Tapable.js:202 next
    [moodi-voting-system]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:202:11

  - CachePlugin.js:78 Compiler.
    [moodi-voting-system]/[webpack]/lib/CachePlugin.js:78:5

  - Tapable.js:206 Compiler.applyPluginsAsyncSeries
    [moodi-voting-system]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:206:13

  - Compiler.js:511 compilation.seal.err
    [moodi-voting-system]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:511:11

  - Tapable.js:195 Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries
    [moodi-voting-system]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:195:46

  - Compilation.js:680 self.applyPluginsAsync.err
    [moodi-voting-system]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:680:19

  - Tapable.js:195 Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries
    [moodi-voting-system]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:195:46

  - Compilation.js:671 self.applyPluginsAsync.err
    [moodi-voting-system]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:671:11

  - Tapable.js:195 Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries
    [moodi-voting-system]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:195:46

  - Compilation.js:666 self.applyPluginsAsync.err
    [moodi-voting-system]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:666:10

  - Tapable.js:195 Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries
    [moodi-voting-system]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:195:46

  - Compilation.js:662 sealPart2
    [moodi-voting-system]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:662:9

  - Tapable.js:195 Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries
    [moodi-voting-system]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:195:46

  - Compilation.js:605 Compilation.seal
    [moodi-voting-system]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:605:8
```

if you have any suggestions please post, thank you.